# php sftp file or folder

Tags: php, sftp

i am attempting to create a web based sftp page, the only part i am having problems with is trying to determin the the listed file is a file or folder. i am sucessfully listing a directory using

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($_SESSION['Server'], $_SESSION['Port']);
if(ssh2_auth_password($connection, $_SESSION['Username'], $_SESSION['Password']))
{
    $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
    $dir = "ssh2.sftp://$sftp/$directory";
    $handle = opendir($dir);
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
    {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
        {
            $temp=$file;
            if(strlen($directory) > 0)
                $Path=$directory."/".$file;
            else
                $Path=$file;

            $statinfo = ssh2_sftp_stat($sftp, "/".$Path);
            echo "<a href=\"list.php?dir=".urlencode($Path)."\">$temp</a><br />";
        }
    }
     closedir($handle);
}
```

i attempted to use the is_dir() and is_file() php function on $file which works sucessfully when working on local filesystem, but when using SFTP both come back FALSE, i attempted to use ssh2_sftp_stat() but this only gives uid, gid, size access and modified times and i dont think there is anyting that can be used to identify files of folders, if anyone has a way to resolve this i would appreaciate it greatly

Vip32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) for SSH2 purposes. It greatly simplifies tasks like this.

Solution for your problem using phpseclib should go something like this:

```
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP($_SESSION['Server'] . ':' . $_SESSION['Port']);
if (!$sftp->login($_SESSION['Username'], $_SESSION['Password'])) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

foreach($sftp->rawlist($dir) as $filename => $attrs) {
    if ($attr['type'] == NET_SFTP_TYPE_REGULAR) {
        echo $filename . ' is a regular file!';
    }
    if ($attr['type'] == NET_SFTP_TYPE_DIRECTORY) {
        echo $filename . ' is a directory!';
    }
}
```

These are the file type constants phpseclib uses:

```
file_types = array(
    1 => 'NET_SFTP_TYPE_REGULAR',
    2 => 'NET_SFTP_TYPE_DIRECTORY',
    3 => 'NET_SFTP_TYPE_SYMLINK',
    4 => 'NET_SFTP_TYPE_SPECIAL'
);
```

Comment: thanks, i am using a combination of the phpseclib along with the ssh2.sftp which seems to be working nicely

Comment: The main reason I am using both is phpseclib has some good futures but I have had to use ssh2.sftp when downloading individual files as I can get it to stream the download directly out to the web browser so on large files you don’t need to wait for the full download and risk browser timeout. The only challenge I have now is creating a preparing download page for downloading mutable files in a zip and not getting any script or browser timeout.